# Set text for label from UIView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have view controller and custom UIView. I ant to set text to label from UIView but I have access to this label only from controller.

How can I get access to this control ?

Comment: Assuming your controller has a reference to your view class, you can always assign a Label property on your UIView in the controller view did load. It might not be the right solution though depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 1):

make the label the property of controller,and the controllerInstance.label is your label instance

UPDATE

The condition when the custom view is the subview to the viewcontroller
you can call for `customView.superview` and from there get to your label as `viewWithTag` setting up an unique tag value to the label

another way is to setup a delegate and pass the value to superview and set it there

Comment: But my uiview dont have access to controller :/

Comment: When I use super view : BallsViewController *controller = self.superview; i get : "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'BallsViewController *__strong' with an expression of type 'UIView *'"

Comment: superview returns viewcontroller's main view not viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tag property of the label. Then use the viewWithTag: method on the view to retrieve the specific label.

Answer (score -1):

You can have a property in the customView which is weak and points to the controller then add a method in the controller that takes a string as parameter and set the text of the label.

Comment: You will create a circular reference. There are some other way to do this (using a tag to retrieve the label from the view) and you should prevent circular references.